# Need code for sampling negative binomial with non-integer $r$

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution

I'm trying to write code (in C) to sample from a negative binomial distribution parameterized by $r,p$, where $r$ is not necessarily integer (also called Polya distribution).

I've found a number of explanations, and it looks like I could sample $y$ from a Gamma(r,1) distribution, transform $y$ somehow, and then use it to sample from a Poisson distribution, but that means I need to find a Gamma distribution with non-integer $r$.

All of this is a bit scary, and I was wondering if anyone could point me to some source code to do it.
I don't much care what language.
I have access to gamma functions, which I'm pretty sure will be needed.

Comment: This is a general comment (and perhaps not helpful), but did you consider sampling from uniform(0,1) and using an inverse probability integral transform (like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling))?

Comment: @RichardHardy: I was hoping for something faster. To use the inverse-transformation, you need to construct the CDF for the specific $r,p$ arguments, and then use some sort of simple search function to invert it. Nevermind, I managed to find info for the Gamma-Poisson method and get it working. Perhaps I will answer my own question. The tricky part is sampling the Gamma for non-integer shape. In Wikipedia I found something called [*Ahrens-Dieter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Generating_gamma-distributed_random_variables) for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally answering my own question...

I found the R source by googling "R source code".
It is [*here*](https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/trunk/src/nmath).

The code for sampling a negative binomial is in `rnbinom.c`.
It does it in two steps.
First it samples from the gamma distribution in `rgamma.c`.
That number is used as the mean of a poisson, defined in `rpois.c`.

I had coded this myself earlier (using Ahrens-Dieter for the gamma distribution) and got something reasonable, but if I generated 1e8 samples, the sample mean would consistently come out around 1/10 of one percent low,
and the sample variance around one percent low.

When I use the source code from R it is more accurate.
If I generate 1e8 samples, the sample mean and variance cluster around their true values.
Whether that is due to a more accurate Gamma distribution, or a more accurate Poisson distribution, I don't know.